# my PC wont go to sleep even though all options are set to put it to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I googled around and just cant figure out why my pc isn't going to sleep

Here are some commands I found to check on sleep setting and my settings that I've done

Some of the commands I tried:
[image: some of the commands I tried]

My power settings:
[image: my power setting]

My sleep settings:
[image: my sleep setting]

My `powercfg /energy` result. It says they don't interfere.
[image: my powercfg /energy result. it says they don't interfere but idk]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Select the “Start” button, then type “device“.
- Open “Device Manager“.
- Expand the “Mice and other pointing devices” section.
- Right-click on the mouse you are using, then choose “Properties“.
- Select the “Power Management” tab.
- Uncheck the “Allow this device to wake the computer” box, then select “OK“.

[image]

Comment: hi. mine is already unchecked, but its still not going to sleep

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Every possible setting was set to "go to bloody sleep!". No issues in `powercfg`. All drivers updated. I eventually gave up and resorted to unplugging every device except the screen and waiting. Guess what? It went to sleep!

I gradually plugged things back in and the culprit was a PS4 controller. Totally ridiculous but if you plug a PS4 controller into my PC via USB it will keep the PC awake and the screen on indefinitely. There's no Power Management tab in its driver settings so you can't really do anything about it as far as I can tell.

One thing I also noticed is that the Power and Sleep timeouts don't seem to be obeyed properly. I set sleep and screen-off to 1 minute, but screen-off actually took about 5 and sleep took more like 20. No idea why but that's good enough for me.